# handleClick selected true when I choose a MenuItem ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a web app using the ReactJS framework.

I am trying to write an event that when I click on one element in a set it changes the value of the selected attribute to true and sets the remaining elements to false.

```
<NavigationButton to="/" label="Dashboard" exact>
<MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={/* true when I click this */}>
    <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
        <Home />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Strona główna" />
</MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
<NavigationButton to="/payment" label="Payment" exact>
<MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={/* false */}>
    <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
        <Payment />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Moje płatności" />
</MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set currently selected value in state and update it on click.

```
<NavigationButton to="/" label="Dashboard" exact>
  <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={this.state.selected === "Dashboard"} onClick={() => {
    this.setState({selected: "Dashboard"})
  }}>
    ...
  </MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
<NavigationButton to="/payment" label="Payment" exact>
  <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={this.state.selected === "Payment"}} onClick={() => {
    this.setState({selected: "Payment"})
  }}>
    ...
  </MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
```

**EDIT:**

On second thought, since you seem to be using `react-router v4`, you can simply add a check for `match.url`:

```
<NavigationButton to="/" label="Dashboard" exact>
  <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={props.match.url === "/"}>
    ...
  </MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
<NavigationButton to="/payment" label="Payment" exact>
  <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={props.match.url === "/payment"}>
    ...
  </MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
```

Comment: selected must be only true or false

Comment: The attribute `selected` is always either `true` or `false` as  `this.state.selected === "Dashboard"` is going to return a boolean.

Comment: I must a create a `state` in my class? what is there to do?

Comment: Not necessarily, it seems you're using react-router. So, you can just use `match.url === "/payment"`

Comment: I don't understand. Could you write to me how it works and write more code?

Comment: I just edited my answer. I hope it makes more sense to you now. In case it's still unclear, I might need you to post your whole code inside `<BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter>`

Comment: I use first method and it's works, but I want `onClick={() => {
    this.setState({selected: "Dashboard"})
  }}>` in new event in my class

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say